# How do I find a resource pack which helps make retextured spiders less scary in 1.12.2?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-resource-packs, wynncraft

(For context, I am arachnophobic. Horribly arachnophobic)

Recently, I've been playing a lot of Wynncraft (a mc java server). However, some areas in the server have lots of retextured spiders (and because of my condition I am blocked off from a lot of the game, like Qira Hive or Temple of Legends). That's why I've tried hunting for a resource pack. However, none of them seem to help with my arachnophobia. The best I can get is a resource pack which retextures vanilla spiders into pig-like creatures. Below is a list of things preventing me from finding the right one

1. My arachnophobia. It is insanely hard to find a resource pack myself without stumbling on "scary spider resource pack" or even a photo of a real spider.
2. I play on 1.12.2. This is a big problem because I cannot drag the pack to the top, overriding the wynncraft pack, due to the fact that it is for a different version.
3. Wynncraft has retextured spiders. For instance, Nivla Forest has the "nesting spider" which is even more horrifying than the vanilla "young forest spider" due to the retextures. Even worse, some of the spiders are armor stand mobs.

Please help! This will not just help me but it will help us arachnophobes who struggle to play minecraft!

Comment: Have you asked the Wynncraft forums yet whether they have a solution?

Comment: I’ve asked on the Wynncraft discord multiple times but they can’t seem to help me.

Comment: Would white spiders satisfy?

Comment: Pig Spiders?
Does the sound need to change as well?

Comment: white spiders? nah wouldnt work

Comment: also the sound IS a pig sound. what i like abt it is that it doesnt look menacing and the legs are invisible

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I got the Wynn resource pack and edited the spiders and their sounds to pigs, floating without legs.

I tested it on the server and it looks fine, but I was just in the start area. But I also tested to make sure spiders looked good in survival and:

[image: Piggies]

Here is the dropbox download:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/j1c2wdkc48syosd/WynnPigSpiders.zip?dl=1

---

Oh, almost forgot, you need to change the settings in the server list on the Wynn server.

In the Minecraft start menu, click `Multiplayer`.

Select the server, don't join just select it.

Press `edit` and a new screen will appear.

Change `Server Resource Pack` from `Enabled` to `Disabled`:

[image: Server]

Comment: Now the trick is to avoid developing a phobia of pigs. Maybe don't watch *Hannibal*.

Comment: You see, I can't accept this answer because there are armorstand/retext spiders, which this pack doesnt work for. also disabling the rpack in the server can cause some... odd glitches

Comment: Also just checking, is the pack for 1.12.2?

Comment: Ye 1.12.2. How does the armorstand retex work?

Comment: You can't disable server-side custom models if that's what they are using. Maby using some kind of client mod, I don't know.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they are retext. They are server-side custom models. Idk how to get a mod tho.